# SSRS. Change background color of specific fields

Tags: reporting-services, background, ssrs-2008, report

I'm creating report with *Visual Studio 2013*. I need to write expresion to change background fields in following:

[image]

For now I have expression:

`= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Grey", "White")`

If I use It on table row's `BackgroundColor` property It returning me following:

[image: wrong]

As you see in left of table I have 3 grouped rows, I need to rewrite expression that It changed color in right side depending on group or (3 white / 3 grey / 3 white / 3 grey and etc)

Comment: to be clear:   right now it looks like the bottom picture, and you want it to look like the top picture?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think this should work, assuming that there are always 3 detail rows for every group:

```
= IIf((RowNumber(Nothing) \ 3) Mod 2 = 0, "Grey", "White")
```